# Handling 'System.DivideByZeroException' On A Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following expression;

```
MyResult = userRecords.Exists(
                    r => ((r.userDataOne + r.userDataTwo) / r.userLimit ) > 0.6m);
```

The issue is that occasionally I will get a 'System.DivideByZeroException' when userLimit is 0.

Currently the only thing I've seen to handling this is a Try/Catch or If statement. I've tried looking for a solution that would work with the lambda statement and handle 0's, am I stuck using multiple 'if' statements? or is there an approach to handling these types of exceptions in a better way?

Comment: Why would userDataOne/Two being zero throw that exception? You are dividing by r.userLimit. It seems like a if statement or ternary operator is going to be your only real solution, I can post an example but it sounds like you've got it covered :)

Comment: You only get a 'Divide by zero' exception if `r.userLimit` is 0, regardless of `r.userDataOne` and `r.userDataTwo`.

Comment: LordTakkera good point, I think I got confused by what was throwing the exception. @Cameron you're totally right, it's the userLimit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not `userDataOne` or `userDataTwo`. The problem is `userLimit`.

You can try avoiding those records like this:

```
userRecords.Where(r => r.userLimit != 0).Exists( ... )
```

or like this:

```
userRecords.Exists(r => r.userLimit != 0 && ((r.userDataOne + r.userDataTwo) / r.userLimit ) > 0.6m);
```